# Aptana Studio Debugger output is delayed and posted to separate window - want to redirect to console

Tags: python, wxpython, stdout, aptana3, stderr

I am using Aptana studio 3.2.2 to develop and debug a python GUI that usese wxPython and matplotlib.

When I stop the debugger at a breakpoint, my console is inactive (this is the console shown at the bottom of the screen in the Aptana Studio PyDev perspective). I can enter text successfully, but nothing is returned on the console after pressing enter.

However, a second window apart from my gui - entitled "wxPython: stdout/stderr" is open. My console output appears here ... BUT ONLY when i resume execution of the script. Before this, the window is non-responsive.

This problem is only happening in windows, when I do the same in a Linux environment, the debugger console works correctly.

Does anyone know how to redirect the console output to ensure it appears in the Aptana console, and also in real time?

Comment: Have you had a look at [wx.App.RedirectStdio](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.App-class.html#RedirectStdio)? It mentions whether the `stdout`/`stderr` should "go to a file or a popup window".

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of hunting and search, the solution turned out to be quite simple. Apparently this is a default behaviour of wx. To fix it, simple use

```
app = wx.App(redirect=False)
```

when creating your Application object.

See http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.App-class.html

Comment: See also my comment, where I posted the same suggestion.